# Meaning of connected components of $GL$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

I know that $GL(n, R)$ consists of two connected components but $GL(n, C)$ consists of one connected component. 
I want to know what makes them difference.

Comment: The determinant split the first one into two, but not the second. ($\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$ is not connected while $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ is connected).

Comment: Have you seen a proof of this fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the determinant function. Any invertible $n\times n$ matrix with real (resp. complex) entries with non-zero determinant are in $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ (resp., $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$).

Then

$${\det}\left(GL(n,\mathbb{R})\right) =  \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$$
$${\det}\left(GL(n,\mathbb{C})\right) = \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$$

For topological spaces $X, Y$ and a continuous surjection $f: X \to Y$, connected components map to connected components. The real (resp. complex) numbers without the origin under the standard topology is our $Y$, our space of matricies is $X$, and $\det$ is our $f$.

Notice that $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ (line without the origin) has two connected components  but $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ is connected (looks like $\mathbb{R}^2$ without the orign).